# Adicionar item à ArrayList toda vez que um objeto for instanciado

Tags: java

Tenho 3 classes: Cliente, Conta e Banco.

```
public class Cliente {
  private String nome;
  private String telefone;

  public Cliente(String n, String t){
    this.nome = n;
    this.telefone = t;
}
(...) + getters e setters
}


public class Conta {
private int numero;
private double saldo;
private Cliente cli;
private Banco banco;

public Conta(Cliente c, int n){
    this.cli = c;
    this.numero = n;
} + getters e setters }


public class Banco {
private ArrayList<Conta> contas;

public Banco(){
    contas = new ArrayList<Conta>();
}
```

Usando mais ou menos essa estrutura, preciso que a cada vez que uma Conta seja criada, ela seja adicionada à ArrayList contas da classe Banco.

Comment: Basta você tornar sua classe Banco uma gerenciadora de contas e clientes, assim, toda vez que precisar criar uma conta, você chamará Banco->adicionarConta, bastando criar a conta e já adicioná-la no array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depende muito da sua modelagem, você antes de mais nada tem que decidir que vai pertencer a quem, e o que faz sentido ser criado sem estar associado a alguém.

Exemplo: É possível criar um cliente que não possui uma conta? De acordo com o que seu código demonstra até o momento, sim. Mas isso é desejável? Não sei. Ninguém melhor do que você para saber isso.

Considerando que sua modelagem lhe atende, o que eu mudaria no momento é criar um método `addConta(Conta c)` na classe Banco e passar o objeto do banco para o construtor da conta (assim, nenhuma conta ficará sem um banco associado a ela), e adicionar cada nova conta logo no construtor da classe `Conta` a lista de contas daquele banco. Exemplo:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Teste {
    public static void main(String [] args){
        Banco b1 = new Banco();
        //.......
        Cliente cli1 = new Cliente("Nome Teste", "Telefone teste");
        Conta cnt1 = new Conta(cli1, 1234, b1);
    }
}

class Cliente {
    private String nome;
    private String telefone;

    public Cliente(String n, String t){
        this.nome = n;
        this.telefone = t;
    }
}

class Conta {
    private int numero;
    private double saldo;
    private Cliente cli;
    private Banco banco;
    public Conta(Cliente c, int n, Banco b){ //passa o objeto de banco para o construtor
        this.cli = c;
        this.numero = n;
        this.banco = b;       //pega a referência do Banco
        banco.addConta(this); //passa a referência da Conta
    }
}

class Banco {
    private List<Conta> contas;
    public Banco(){
        contas = new ArrayList<Conta>();
    }
    public void addConta(Conta c) { //novo método
        this.contas.add(c);
    }   
}
```

Comment: Cheguei atrasado :/ Mas com certeza sua resposta está mais completa e exemplificada.

Comment: @DiegoFelipe sempre tem algo que pode ser considerado (ok, nem sempre, mas nesse caso eu desconfio que sim), talvez ainda tenha espaço para mais respostas :)